# HTTP Requests in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a weird problem with Phonegap. My XMLHttpRequests fire twice; I'm using XMLHttpRequests in an app I'm developing to create a dynamic list of events to select. jQuery is also one of the libs I'm using.

Any time I use an XMLHttpRequest, either vanilla or jQuery, it does it twice, even though it should only run once. Has anyone else ran into this problem?

Some example code here:

```
(function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://{site-url-hidden-for-privacy}/events/list", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        if(request.status == 200 || request.status == 0){
            parse_events(JSON.parse( request.responseText ));
        }               
    }
}
request.send();
})();
```

the XMLHttpResponse text is a JSON array, and parse_events simply takes that array and uses it to create a set of select options for a menu.

Does anyone know why this would fire twice, essentially creating two options for each event, when there should only be one?

Comment: How are you verifying that onreadystatechange fires twice? Two identical requests returning once each could look very similar.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't super clear, but what seems to be going on is that the anonymous function above fires twice, ie, two identical requests returning once each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got it figured out. I was working on this project with a co-worker, and we forgot to listen for the deviceready event to fire, since we're using phonegap. We were binding the "online" and "offline" events when the window loaded, not when the device was ready.

Before:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.addEventListener("online", function(){...}, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", function(){...}, false);
}, false);
```

Solution:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
        document.addEventListener("online", function(){...}, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", function(){...}, false);
    },false);
}, false);
```

I'm not sure why, as it doesn't make total sense, but I think not going through "deviceready" was causing the HTTP request to go twice, once when the page loaded, and once when the device was ready.

The fix was to make it only go when the device was ready, as shown above.